# Nginx no access log file

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

## nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes 8;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  2048;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent $request_time $upstream_response_time "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    server_tokens   off;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    # set_real_ip_from

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/app.conf;
}
```

## app.conf

```
server {
    listen 8000 default_server;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    location /ping {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///var/data/recommendation/api/run/uwsgi.sock;
        # uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param Host $host;
        uwsgi_param X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        uwsgi_param X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        uwsgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///var/data/recommendation/api/run/uwsgi.sock;
        # uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

## Docker file

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/nginx/nginx:latest as nginx
COPY recommendation/api/nginx/conf.d/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/
COPY recommendation/api/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

... some other django image build code

# nginx configs for ecs nginx container.
# nginx container uses this container's volume
COPY --from=nginx /etc/nginx /etc/nginx
VOLUME ["/etc/nginx"]
```

I am using Nginx + uwsgi + django + docker for my webserver.
I need access log to investigate empty_response issue for my django server on local machine(localhost:8000). However, I do not see any of access log or error log created in the desired location.
What settings did I put wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At the console of your container nginx try
cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

You shoud see somethind like
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

Refer to nginx documentation for details about error_log and access_log.